# C++ save image as SVG

Tags: c++, windows, svg

I have to save my chart as SVG file (my enviroment `C++`, `eclipse C/C++`, `windows 7`).
I'm able to save it as image file (as you can see bellow), but it's not enough.

[image]

I've tried:

- **[gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)** (`gnuplot_i.hpp`): don't know how to save the image as SVG file
- **[simple-svg](http://code.google.com/p/simple-svg/)**: don't know how not to show black points
- **[cairo](http://cairographics.org/)**: i'm not able to use it at all

Could you recommend me some light and **easy-to-understand-and-install** tool which helps me to draw charts in `C++` and save it **directly** as SVG file (so nothing like `jpg2svg convertor`:-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly do you obtain that image? Is there something specific to it that prevents you from just `fprintf`-ing the image, since SVG is an XML (text) file format?

Comment: Thank you, the `fprintf`-ing method really works and is well described on the net

Answer (score 2):

I know in command-line gnuplot, it is possible to save a plot as a SVG by doing:

```
> set term svg
> plot ...
```

Looking over [gnuplot_i.hpp](http://code.google.com/p/gnuplot-cpp/source/browse/trunk/gnuplot_i.hpp?r=5), I would suggest trying:

```
Gnuplot myGP;
myGP.set_terminal_std("svg");
myGP.setGNUPlotPath("/your/path/here");
myGP.showonscreen();
```

While I haven't tested it (and there may be more complexity in the Gnuplot class than I can see from the header file), the general idea is there. Set the terminal to svg, set the output path, and plot.